# Setting an icon from inside a frameset

Tags: html, hyperlink, frameset

I am using GoDaddy to have a mask of my website. When a user goes directly to the actual address of the site, the icon shows in the browser tab. When they go to the GoDaddy address, it doesn't show.

GoDaddy uses a `<frameset>` to perform the mask. The icon is set through `<link href="http://THEACTUALADDRESS/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/icon">`. When I go to the link `http://THEACTUALADDRESS/favicon.ico`, the icon can be seen; that's not the problem.

Is it possible to set the website's icon from within a `<frameset>`? I have tried to use `target="_top"` inside the `<link>` but that does not fix the issue.
This is the code returned from the GoDaddy address:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>THEACTUALADDRESS</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://THEACTUALADDRESS" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 12 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

And the code at `http://THEACTUALADDRESS/`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="http://THEACTUALADDRESS/favicon.ico" type="image/icon" target="_top"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700|Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...the rest of the page
```

Comment: This is an issue that you shouldn't even be **trying** to resolve, as [**`<frameset>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset) has long since been deprecated. Use `<iframe>` instead :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge I would love to use a different method, but GoDaddy doesn't appear to have any other options for masking.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to put the code in the framset index.html AND use a favicon.PNG. Then the icon appears in the framset AND at the actual site.